# Need help with creating/using a co-recursive workflow template in Sharepoint Designer 2010

Tags: designer-workflow, workflow-template

I have co-recursive workflows, WF-A and WF-B, that work together to send out an email. I created and tested them on my own test SharePoint site and they are working great. But I need them on another site that I cannot open with SharePoint Designer 2010 because it is set up to not allow it at the server level to which I cannot change. So I was going to export them as templates from my test site to this other site. 
   The problem is, they both need to be able to use a yes/no column that is used indicate whether an email should be sent. I cannot figure out how, if there is even a way, to export these workflows and still have them be able to use the same yes/no column. So I'm looking for anyway to have these 2 separate workflows reference the same column after being exported then imported, or if there is another way to get it onto the other site altogether.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a custom type that is a child of an "Item" that carried all the necessary columns. Then I created the reusable workflows for this new custom type.